# Selecting an ID which matches a user input in SQLite3 Python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, matplotlib

I'd like to give the user an option to select an ID to view a matplotlib report from... However, I am stuck on selecting data where the category matches the user input (id_input)

```
if report_option == "A":
    print("Expense Report by Category: \n")
    id_input = input("Please enter the ID of the Category you would like to view: \n")
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM tblCategory")
    for row in c.fetchall():
        print(row)
    c.execute('SELECT CategoryID, AmountSpent FROM tblFinance')
    categories = []
    amountspent = []
    for row in c.fetchall():
        print(row[0])
        categories.append(row[0])
        amountspent.append(row[1])

    plt.plot(categories, amountspent)
    plt.ylabel('Amount Spent')
    plt.xlabel('Category ID')
    plt.show()
    menu()
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!!

Comment: Please add some sample data from both tables which shows what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your trying to select `AmountSpent` from `tblFinance` where `CategoryID` is what the user input is.

```
id_input = input("Please enter the ID of the Category you would like to view: \n")
data = []
for row in c.execute("SELECT AmountSpent FROM tblFinance WHERE CategoryID=?", (id_input, )):
   data.append(row)
return data #use data variable here however you need with matplotlib
```

Explanation:

You want to create a SELECT x FROM y WHERE z = a statement, which selects x from table y, where z is a. Basically what it says. You can use `?` and a second parameter to get data based on an input. If you have more questions, let me know.

Edit:

If you want to select both AmountSpent AND CategoryID, replace the SQL statement with `"SELECT CategoryID, AmountSpent FROM tblFinance WHERE CategoryID=?"`

Comment: Hmm ok, I'd like to select both the CategoryID and the AmountSpent to display to the user in a graph, all I'd like to know is just how I can select both from a user input variable, would it be possible to use the code you provided but use: 
("SELECT CategoryID, AmountSpent FROM tblFinance WHERE CategoryID=?", (id_input, ))
Instead so I can display both?

Comment: That would work, you are just also selecting CategoryID along with AmountSpent.

Comment: Updated to include that

Comment: I tried that however, when I execute the command, the matplotlib graph doesn't display any datá correctly...

Comment: The issue is not with the query, it is probably related to matplotlib or your data. The query will select the rows you need. Make sure to at least print the data out once, and check if they are in the format you want.

Comment: Ok, thank you, it's almost working! (Thanks for your help btw, I'm new to this stuff!) It only prints the first data entry into the matplotlib graph? E.g. CategoryID may have one input as 200 and a second 100 however, the graph only shows 200. This is my updated code in the new answer section:

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct, if it solved your problem. Thanks

Comment: @keez, use your original setup of building two separate lists but use the parameterized query shown here.

Comment: I've done so, however, only the first data entry which relates to the categoryID is displayed in the graph

Comment: Please post your current code at http://hastebin.com, and link it to us

Comment: The current code being used is below in a seperate answer

Comment: Please contact me via Chat or via Discord @ Sxribe#1182